# cursor performace with mongodb php driver

Tags: php, mongodb, cursor, driver

Is there any performance issues with php mongo query cursor handling?

**My code:**

```
 $cursor = $collection->find($searchCriteria)->limit($limit_rows);
// Sort ascending based on S_DTTM
$cursor->sort(array('S_DTTM' => 1 , 'SYMBOL' => 1 ));

// How many results found?
$num_docs = $cursor->count(); 

if( $num_docs > 0 )
{
    // loop over the results
    foreach ($cursor as $ticks)
    {
```

See codes like

```
// request data 
$result = $cursor->getNext();
```

My issue is after the first query returns ( full with limit  of 100 rows ) the next query just goes on looping. Have  millions of rows returning, so I wanted to put the limits with "limit".

I did do re-index just in case, still no difference.

What am I doing wrong? Does the getNext works better?

Using mongod ver 2.5.4  and the latest php mongo driver downloaded a week ago.
Collection size is 100Gb including 2 additional indexes.

mongo log shows all the query executing in less than 200ms.

- Turns out to be Query Issue and not php mongo driver issue ..

Comment: Are you sure that the limit is being applied correctly? Have you var_dumped the `$limit_rows` var to make sure it is actually limiting?

Comment: Also what is the criteria of the "next query"?

Comment: how big is your limit?  and do you have an index on the collection on the fields you are querying and/or sorting by?

Comment: my limit is 100 default value   and I am not using the getNext() just wanted to confirm it is the one that I should be using.. I do have index on the find query...  not sure how the sort is working..   .. I am testing if the data load of the search criteria  is pulling a lot of data for the sort and then limit is working  ..

Comment: What is the output if you run this query and use .explain()

Comment: without the sort  it shows using the correct index and comes quickly ( less than 100mns ) with the sort   it hangs and my pc ( T1600 8gb 4 core ) runs at 98% waio .. and I have to pull plug and restart :)

Comment: that means you're forcing it to do an in memory sort which is very expensive - you want to have sort use an index same as find...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use of `count()` and `sort()` may decrease performance.

Comment: Why would sort decrease performance? Also you don't explain why count can

Comment: testing if that's the reason.. remember my query will return a lot of rows too.. thats why the limit

Comment: ** Looks like the Sort is really the culprit. **
[documentation]: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/
states to use limit to avoid in memory  sort ..  but  in my case its pull the whole record set for the find  based on col1  and the sorting it in memory and then applying the limit    **  any suggestions to avoid the in memory sort  is appreciated  **

Comment: @mpaul did you try "compound index"?

Comment: so I have a ticks collections which has symbol and datetime fields    now the query [ find( {SYMBOL : "E:MSFT"}).sort({DATETIME:1})  ] uses the "symbol" index and  not the compound index ( datetime, symbol)   and the sorting in memory for the sample say 20Gb data. causing the issue.

Comment: Modified query  and forced the compound index ..find( {"DATETIME" : { "$gte" : ISODate("2013-12-30")} , SYMBOL : "E:MSFT"}).sort({ "DATETIME" : 1 }).hint("idx_dt_symbol")   works ok now....     Thanks  to all..